# Limit number of active threads in LMAX Disruptor(RingBuffer)

Tags: c#, multithreading, circular-buffer, disruptor-pattern, lmax

I have multiple consumers of different types that *can* be run in parallel but I don't want *all of them* to run in parallel *at the same time* because I don't have that many CPU cores and performance would degrade because of context switching. How is such case usually solved with disruptor-net?

Comment: It’s hard to see how the disruptor would be useful in this use case without some more information. Are your consumers stateful? Do they interact with each other? Anything else you could add to the question would help.

Comment: Does each consumer have to process each event or are different types of events procssed by different types of consumers?